Angular interceptor error handling put & delete method problem
I show an alert based on the http response returned in Angular. My code works in Get and post methods, but not in put and delete methods.I'm stuck here and would be very happy if someone could help me.
ApiUrl.ts =>
export const AlertUrls: string[] = [ // backend service urls ]
my-interceptor.ts =>
import { AlertUrls, collection } from "../ApiUrl";
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
        if ( AlertUrls.includes(req.url) && req.method !=='GET' && response instanceof HttpResponse && response.status === 200) {
          this.alertService.showSuccessAlert();
        }
    return response;
  }),


put a debugger on the if condition and check it manually! one of the if conditions is evaluating to false, should be done by you!

@NarenMurali Actually When the debugger is opened, while the post method is running, next to the following value => map((response: any) => { response = HttpResponse { header: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: '(backend service url)', ok: true, ...}
A line like this appears and when I continue the debugger, the same line appears next to this code: response instanceof HttpResponse &&.

@NarenMurali
However, when the debugger is turned on and the put and delete methods are running, next to the value here, map((response: any) => the line above is output.
response instanceof HttpResponse && does not write any code next to the value here. Do you think the problem might be related to this?

you can just console.log(AlertUrls.includes(req.url), req.method !=='GET',  response instanceof HttpResponse,  response.status === 200) to check all the individual if conditions, if the debugger is giving you issues!

@NarenMurali Url is not mathcing completely with our delete url because of our delete item id. So it's not get in the if condition. That is the problem actually but i'm still figure out how can i solve this problem.

Url not matching is the problem you are facing, you can simply use the string property, includes to check if the string is present inside the url, instead of doing a full equality check!
AlertUrl: /delete
will match for
Full URL: /delete/123uuh4u23424
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
        if (AlertUrls.find((url: any) => req.url.includes(url)) && req.method !=='GET' && response instanceof HttpResponse && response.status === 200) {
          this.alertService.showSuccessAlert();
        }
    return response;
  }),


I solved like this.  return next.handle(req).pipe(
map((response: any) => {
console.log(AlertUrls)
console.log(req.url)
let cloneReq = req.url;
let reqSplit = req.url.split('=');
console.log(reqSplit)
if(reqSplit.length>1){
cloneReq = reqSplit[0] + "=" ;
}
if ( AlertUrls.includes(cloneReq) && response instanceof HttpResponse && response.status === 200) {
this.alertService.showSuccessAlert();
}
    return response;
  }),


But your method worked too. I tried few minutes ago. So thank you so much.  Especially for your debugger idea . Because that's how I was able to detect the problem. Thank you again ^^
